# Is it possible to have a script search a web page for a price

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started to learn java script (like last week so I am a noob) and I was just wondering is it possible to have a script search a web page for a certain number or lower and if it finds the number or lower then notify me in a certain way also refresh the page every minute?

Comment: There is [*Greasemonkey*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox, not difficult if you have reasonable criteria to identify the element or text in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into building extensions for your browser. Chrome for example supports creating extensions with javascript: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

It's a long way from there to the functionality you want, if you got specific questions, post them here separately.